# appropriate Word for transfering student from one university to another university

Tags: university, international-students, international, transfer-student, keywords

I am searching an appropriate word for **transferring student from one University to another University**
There might be such a word which helps me to search for related topics of transferring student from one university to another one.

Comment: Is this for students who initiate the transfer or for students who a moved by the universities?

Comment: @SolarMike I am particularly searching for a student who initiates the transfer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use the term "transfer student" that you've already used in the question tags.

[Collin's Dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transfer-student)

> a student who moves from one institution or course to another at the same level (e.g. undergraduate)

A student can both be said to apply to the new university as a transfer student, and be described as a transfer student at the start of their study at the new university ([example](https://admissions.colostate.edu/apply/transfer/)).